# Need help making a line graph from an array and I would like custom tick labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, linechart

I plan on getting votes from users and displaying the last three months results in a line graph. Through out the months they will be clicking a "good" or "bad" button. here is some data that I will try to make it look like when it comes from the server.

```
    var results = {
        "month1" : {"good" : 400,"bad" : 30} ,
        "month2" : {"good" : 200, "bad" : 100},
        "month3" : {"good" : 100, "bad" : 200}

    };
```

I thought I would I get an array like [370, 100, -100] subtracting the good from the bad. I guess these will be points on graph that the line will go through. so at "1 month" (this is on the x axis) the line will go through 370 and on "2 month" the line will go through 100 and at "3 month" the line will go through -100.

- I guess the y axis should be scaled from -100 to 370
- There should be three ticks on the x axis `tickLabels = ["1 mo", "2 mo", "3 mo"]`

Here is what I have so far I know it's not a lot because I got confused.

```
var results = {
        "month1" : {"good" : 400,"bad" : 30} ,
        "month2" : {"good" : 200, "bad" : 100},
        "month3" : {"good" : 100, "bad" : 200}

    };

    var arr = []

    for(var key in results){
        var obj = results[key];
        arr.push(obj.good - obj.bad)
    }
    console.log(arr)

    var margin = {top : 30, right : 20, bottom : 30, left: 50},
            width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width])
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

    var tickLabels = ["1 mo", "2 mo", "3 mo"]

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(function(d, i) { return tickLabels[i]})

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(5)
```

I was following along some tutorials and the next part goes like this:

```
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) {return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) {return y(d.close); });
```

I don't have `date` or `close` obviously. I just didn't know  how to apply a line generator to my data. so can you  help me finish up the graph with the proper tick labels, `1 mo` etc.? That will be very helpful.

EDIT ::: I will show you what I have now

It looks like I need to scale the x values properly to match to the axis

```js
  var results = {
         "month1" : {"good" : 400,"bad" : 30} ,
         "month2" : {"good" : 200, "bad" : 100},
         "month3" : {"good" : 100, "bad" : 200}

     };

  var arr = []

  for(var key in results){
   var obj = results[key];
   arr.push(obj.good - obj.bad)
  }
  console.log(arr)

  var margin = {top : 30, right : 20, bottom : 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  var x = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width])
  var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

  var tickLabels = ["1 mo", "2 mo", "3 mo"]

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickFormat(function(d, i) { return tickLabels[i]})

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left").ticks(5)

  var valueline = d3.svg.line()
   .x(function(d, i) {return x(i)})
   .y(function(d) {return y(d)})

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
   .attr("width" , width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

   y.domain([d3.min(arr, function(d) {return d} ), d3.max(arr, function(d) {return d} )])

   svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(yAxis)

   svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").call(xAxis).attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")

  svg.append("path").attr("d", valueline(arr)).style({"fill" : "none", "stroke" : "blue"})
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your x axis shows months, so you can refer to the index of the Array arr. Your y axis shows value(good-bad), so it becomes value at that index. So if Array arr is your dataset, your valueline should be:

```
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d,i) {return x(i); })
    .y(function(d) {return y(d); });
```

Added this and couple of more changes on domain/range/tick on axis in your code: [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lua5q0q7/)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your helpful response. Now I would like you to help me scale the x values. Right now it looks like the 3rd point on the line is going off the svg and the "1 mo 2 mo 3 mo" ticks are bunched together on the right side. I feel like I should use `x.domain(` but I don't know how to use it in this case. I updated  the question to show where I'm up to.

Comment: I did `x.domain([0, 2])` and it makes the line line look like it matches the data properly but I still didn't get the month label to spread out

Comment: I put the working code that I have in the question above. you could even click "Run code snippet" and see what I have.

Comment: check out the answer now.. made some changes to your code... there was an issue with domain & Range, plus how you use ticks

Comment: Again thanks for your response. one last thing before I accept your answer. the tick labels  are not being spread out the whole width of the graph. The `3mo` should be at the end of the x axis on the right side. all the  labels and the corresponding point on the graph should be spread out for the entire width. After you fix this I will accept your answer. Thanks

Comment: come on man... thats quite tough to fix.... :(. maybe if you are extremely lucky, changing 'arr.length' to 'arr.length - 1' on xaxis domain() & ticks() can do that... all the best :p